# Nicest way to calculate "update rate" on a SQL server table row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics, usage-statistics

I'm thinking a trigger is my best option here, but wanted to see if there's something I've overlooked.

I've got a table with an ID(Primary key) and a last updated date and I'd like to find out which IDs in this table are being updated the most often. At the moment I'm not sure how big a "window" I'd like to look across (most updated per hour, day, week etc.) so I'm hoping to get either a computed column or a trigger that lets me specify the timeframe and then we can gather data to look at.

Naturally we could write custom code in the application to do this, but it'd be nice if it was all handled by SQL server.

Comment: Keep track of each update using a log table and do the analysis afterwards using whatever time frame you like.

Comment: And a built-in solution is to make this a Temporal Table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Temporal tables look absolutely Ideal. Thanks, I'll investigate them

Comment: if your sql version is less than 2016 maybe you should take a look at this other [cdc solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).